# How to convert Encoded url into JSON format?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Here I want to convert my encoded url into JSON format. The encoded url is:

```
http://localhost:63342/AngularJs/services/e_cell.html#!/%7B%22book%22:%22ABC%22%7D
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Show us your expected output.

Comment: have u even tried to search on stackoverflow..it asked many times.. try if it works for you `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify("http://localhost:63342/AngularJs/services/e_cell.html#!/%7B%22book%22:%22ABC%22%7D"))`

Comment: This code again encode the URL !!@Dhara

Answer (score 8):

As much as I understand from  your URL you are trying to post this `%7B%22book%22:%22ABC%22%7D` data in query string.

So first you need to decode your URL encoded data into an string which can be parsed. For that you can take help of `decodeURIComponent()` javascript API.

`decodeURIComponent()` - this function decodes an encoded URI component back to the plain text i.e. like in your encoded text it will convert `%7B` into opening brace `{`. So once we apply this API you get -

```
//output : Object { book: "ABC" }
```

This is a valid JSON string now you can simply parse. So what all you need to do is -

```
var formData = "%7B%22book%22:%22ABC%22%7D";
var decodedData = decodeURIComponent(formData);
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(decodedData);
console.log(jsonObject );
```

The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string

Comment: OP wants to convert the form data `%7B%22book%22:%22ABC%22%7D` that he is posting in the URL as query string into JSON using javascript APIs but you have converted the whole URL instead. You don't convert it into JSON format in the end.

Answer (score 1):

[The `decodeURIComponent` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) will convert URL encoded characters back to plain text.

```
var myJSON = decodeURIComponent("%7B%22book%22:%22ABC%22%7D");
var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSON);
```